# Representation decomposition over $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory, tensor-products

I have found that $Sym^2(V) \otimes Sym^2(V)$ can be decomposed over the special linear group  as follows:

$Sym^2(V) \otimes Sym^2(V) \simeq Sym^4(V) \oplus Sym^2(V) \oplus 1$

This is done using the highest weights and vectors of $Sym^2(V)$

---

> How do we decompose $Sym^2(V) \otimes Sym^2(V)$ into irreducible representations over  $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

I have seen the answer in my course is $Sym^2(V) \otimes Sym^2(V) \simeq Sym^4(\mathbb{C^2}) \oplus (Sym^2(\mathbb{C^2}) \otimes det) \oplus (det)^2$

So why is this similar to the first example but with extra $det$ terms?

Comment: Is it surprising that the difference between $SL_2$ and $GL_2$ is the determinant ?

Comment: Well I suppose $SL_2$ has the condition that $det=1$